# Understanding 8086 assembler debugger

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86-16

I'm learning assembler and I need some help with understanding codes in the debugger, especially the marked part.

```
mov     ax, a
mov     bx, 4
```

I know how above instructions works, but in the debugger I have "2EA10301" and "BB0400".

What do they mean?
The first instruction moves variable a from data segment to the `ax` register, but in debugger I have `cs:[0103]`.

What do mean these brackets and these numbers?

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First, I believe that's "**2**EA10301", and it's hexadecimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `2EA10301` and `BB0400` numbers are the [opcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) for the two instructions highlighted.

`2E` is [Code Segment (CS) prefix](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0240_prefix.htm) and instructs the CPU to access memory with the `CS` segment instead of the default `DS` one.
`A1` is the opcode for `MOV AX, moffs16` and `0301` is the immediate 0103h in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), the address to read from.
So `2EA10301` is `mov ax, cs:[103h]`.
The square brackets are the preferred way to denote a [memory access through one the addressing mode](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH04/CH04-2.html#HEADING2-26) but some assemblers support the confusing syntax without the brackets.
As this syntax is ambiguous and less standardised across different assemblers than the other, it is discouraged.

During the assembling the assembler keeps a location counter incremented for each byte emitted (each "section"/segment has its own counter, i.e. the counter is reset at the beginning of each "section").
This gives each variable an offset that is used to access it and to craft the instruction, variables names are for the human, CPUs can only read from addresses, numbers.

This offset will later be and address in memory once the file is loaded.
The assembler, the linker and the loader cooperate, [there are various tricks at play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)), to make sure the final instruction is properly formed in memory and that the offset is transformed into the right address.
In your example their efforts culminate in the value 103h, that is the address of `a` in memory.
Again, in your example, the offset, if the file is a COM (by the way, don't put variables in the execution flow), was still 103h due to the peculiar structure of the COM files.
But in general, it could have been another number.

`BB` is `MOV r16, imm16` with the register `BX`. The base form is `B8` with the lower 3 bits indicating the register to use, `BX` is denoted by a value of 3 (011b in binary) and indeed 0B8h + 3 = 0BBh.
After the opcode, again, the WORD immediate `0400` that encodes 4 in little endian.

---

You now are in the position to realise that the assembly source is not always fully informative, as the assemblers implement some form of syntactic sugar.
The instruction `mov ax, a`, identical to `mov bx, 4` in its syntax and that technically is *move the **immediate** value, constant and known at assembly time, given by the address of `a` into `ax`*, is instead interpreted as *move the **content** of `a`, a value present in memory and readable only with a memory access, into `ax`* because `a` is known to be a variable.

This phenomenon is limited in the x86, being [CISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computing), and more widespread in the [RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) world, where the lack of commonly needed instructions is compensated with [pseudo-instructions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions).

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, assembler is x86 Assembly. The assembler is what turns the instructions into machine code.

When you disassemble programs, it probably will use the hex values (like 90 is NOP instruction or B8 to move something to AX).

Square brackets copies the memory address to which the register points to.
The hex on the side is called the address.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is very simple. The command mov ax, cx: [0103] means that the value of 000Ah is loaded into the register ax. This value is taken from the code segment at 0103h. Slightly higher in the pictures you can see this value. cx: 0101 0B900A00. Accordingly, at the address 0101h to be the value 0Bh, 0102h to be the value 90h, 0103h to be the value 0Ah, 0104h to be the value 00h. It turns out that the AL register loads the value from the address 0103h equal to 0Ah. It turns out that the AH register loads the value from the address 0104h equal to 00h and it turns out ax = 000Ah. If instead of the ax command, cx: [0103] there was the ax command, cx: [0101], then ax = 900Bh or the ax command, cx: [0102], then ax = 0A90h.